# Regexp with variable

Tags: php, regex

I am usign a flatfile database with a delimiter character, the delimiter character is defined by the user and stored in `$this->_config->delimiter()`. I want to run Regexp on the input string to safely escape both the delimiter character and the `\` character e.g.

```
// $this->_config->delimiter() = "|"
$input = "the quick | brown \ fox jumped";
// function returning output here
$output = "the quick \| brown \\ fox jumped";
```

If you know a better/faster way of doing this without regexp I am open to that aswell.

Is it possible to do this with a variable in the regex?

Comment: Are you using a function as a variable? How can you do `someFunction() = '|'`?

Comment: @Oltarus `$_config` is a variable that stores an instance of another class, `delimiter()` is a getter function which returns the delimiter from that instance. Hope that makes sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a regex. Do:

```
str_replace(array('\\', $this->_config->delimiter()),
            array('\\\\', '\\' . $this->_config->delimiter()),
            $variable);
```

Comment: Shouldn't I put `array('\', $this->_config->delimiter()),
            array('\\', '\' . $this->_config->delimiter())`, why the double backslashes? NVM - I see because it is escaping the quotes in the array :P

Comment: BTW make sure to do them in that order. If you put delimiter first then backslash, the backslash will also escape the backslash you just added in front of the delimiter. (The function works from left to right.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`strtr` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php):

```
$input = strtr($input, array(
    $this->_config->delimiter() => '\\' . $this->_config->delimiter(),
    '\\' => '\\\\'
));
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.org/RLa1Y5Rd)

Comment: @Ariel: Have you tried the demo? Works for me. If you pass an array, you can use any string.

Comment: Yah, just double checked the docs. Looks like they special cased the array version of the function.